# sqlplus return same rows

Tags: sql

I need help with sqlplus. Let's say I do have a table called employment with columns **Name** and **Job**. I want to return the **Names** with **same Job**.

Table:

```
Name  Job

John  KPMG
Mike  Morgan Stanley
Alan  Delloite
Anna  Ernst and Young
Tom   KPMG
Fran  Delloite
```

Comment: what will be you desired result?

Answer (score 1):

To determine which jobs have more than one name, do this

```
select count(name), job
from employment
group by job
having count(name) > 1
```

to then get a list of names for each of these jobs,

```
select count(emp_count.name), emp_count.job, emp_names.name
from employment emp_count
  inner join employment emp_names on emp_count.job = emp_names.job
group by emp_count.job
having count(emp_count.name) > 1
```

You could also simply

```
select * from employment order by job
```

which would put all duplicate jobs together in the listing.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name from employment where Job = 'KPMG';
```

This will return

**Name**

John

Tom

Comment: I want output to be John, Tom, Alan and Fran. Can't just use where Job='...'

Comment: if you want it in a single query the use `where Job = 'KPMG' or Job = 'Delloite'`

Answer (score 0):

you can have a query like,

select name, job from emp where job = 'Deloitte';

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

select name from employment where job in (select job from employment group by job having count(job) > 1);